# How to use tally from loop outside of that loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, count

New to coding, sorry if the question is too simple.

I am trying to keep a tally of how many times a character in a certain string range appears. I want to use that tally, `count`, later and add it to different values, and other tallies. If I return it I can't seem to be able to reuse it. How would I be able to reuse the tally, but outside of the loop?

```
def function(word):
    letters = 'abcdefgh'
    while count < len(word):
       for i in word:
          if i in letters:
              count += 1
        return count
     a = count + 5
     print(a)
print(function('AaB5a'))
```

`count` should be 2, but how do I take it, and add it to other values, like `a = count + 5`? `print(a)` does not print 7, or anything.

Comment: You are returning before you reach those lines `return count` so nothing after that gets executed

Comment: How would I return so the while loop keeps going and `count` keeps its added value?

Comment: You *don't* return if you want the loop to keep going.

Comment: Also, you are referencing `count` before assinging to it, which will raise an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: You have to return *after* what you want to do is done

Comment: You're also using count for two things: iterating through words and keeping track of how many words match your condition. You should use separate variables for these two things.

Comment: The outer `while` loop is redundant, and will never terminate for some inputs (e.g. "xyz") - so it should be removed. You also need to initialise the counter before starting the for-loop (i.e. `count = 0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most of the comments already covered, you should remove the return to the end, and also the while loop doesn't seem to be required (and in fact, appears to provide a wrong result).
Please let me know if this is not what you wanted, and I will correct it based on your input, but it does output 2 and prints 7 as you requested in OP

```
def function(word):
    count = 0
    letters = 'abcdefgh'
    for i in word:
        if i in letters:
            count += 1
    a = count + 5
    print(a)
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably not use the word function to name your function. I changed your sample to `check_letters`
You also want to create the variable count outside of the while loop so you can save the incremented count. At the end, return the count.

```
def check_letters(word):
    letters = 'abcdefgh'
    count = 0
    while count < len(word):
        for i in word:
            if i in letters:
               count += 1
    return count
```

Once that is done, you can call the function and pass in your paramenter, it will return an int which in this case, you want to add 5. We're then saving the results to the variable

`a = check_letters('AaB5a') + 5`

`print (a)`

`11`

if you print the check letters, you'll get the return count to the output.

```
print (check_letters('AaB5a'))
6
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to debug his code, just show him where he was going wrong and point him in the right direction. His method has other issues I agree.

Answer (score 0):

> I set the count variable to zero because it throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment.  The function will return the count of the string passed in.  The count is now returned by the function.  You can then assign it to a variable and then add, subtract, etc., to that variable.

```
def function(word):
    letters = 'abcdefgh'
    count=0
    while count < len(word):
        for i in word:
            if i in letters:
                count += 1
    return count

c=function('AaB5a')
a=c + 5
print(a)
```

Comment: It would be better to explain the solution using informal language in addition to the code. While a code block is the best demonstration of a concept it almost useless unless you described that concept in words.

Comment: The answer was explained by the time I posted but i will update the response to clarify the concept with words.